# Legend marker in pgfplot bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I spent the last hours trying to solve this issue. I hope you can help me, sorry if the answer appears clearly somewhere else, I was not able to find it.

I would like to adjust the marker/symbol in the legend for the first plot. I tried with the following (making them green and blue):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
Label   First Second   
1    5      56.1    
2     22        56.5    
3     5         44.3   
4    5  42.0   
}\datatablet
\begin{axis}[
xbar,
]
\addplot [fill=black]           table [y=Label, x=First] {\datatablet};  
\addplot [fill=black!20!white]  table  [y=Label, x=Second]  {\datatablet}; 
\addlegendimage{area legend,fill=green}\addlegendentry{TEST}  
\addlegendimage{area legend, fill=blue} \addlegendentry{TEST2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

which gives me thefollowing output..

[image]
what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help, Ilkay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't understand why do you want the legend to be of a different colour (it goes against the utility of a legend) but anyway the answer is to define your own styles with the colours already included in this way as in the following. The code is taken from the `pgfplots` manual from the default definition of the `xbar legend` style (last part of **Legend Appearance** section), I have only add the colour definition.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    xbar legend green/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[/tikz/.cd,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt,fill=green] plot coordinates {(0cm,0.8em) (2*\pgfplotbarwidth,0.6em)};
        },
    },
    xbar legend blue/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[/tikz/.cd,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt,fill=blue] plot coordinates {(0cm,0.8em) 2*\pgfplotbarwidth,0.6em)};
        },
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
Label   First Second   
1    5      56.1    
2     22        56.5    
3     5         44.3   
4    5  42.0   
}\datatablet
\begin{axis}[
xbar,
]
\addplot [fill=black,xbar legend green]           table [y=Label, x=First] {\datatablet};   
\addplot [fill=black!20!white,xbar legend blue]  table  [y=Label, x=Second]  {\datatablet};
\legend{test,test2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]